# Jquery click event doesn't fire with Handlebars template

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, frontend

I have a problem with Jquery .on() function and Handlebars template. I wroted Handlebars template and add him dynamically in document:

```
$('.services-wrapper').append(serviceTemplate({index : ++maxIndex}));
```

This template has a button:

```
<p>
    <?= Html::buttonInput('Delete', [
    'class' => 'btn btn-danger delete-service', 
    'id' => 'js-delete-service',
        'data' => [
        'index' => $index,
    ],
    ]) ?>
</p>
```

So I wroted click handler on this button:

```
$('.service').on('click', '.delete-service', function (e) {
    alert('Clicked');
    //$(this).parent().parent().remove();
});
```

When I add this template to document, click event doesn't fire. What is the problem?

Comment: Please post the answer if it worked. I am facing similar issue while using mousemove event with handlebars.

Answer (score 1):

You might need a closest parent wrapper as:

```
$('.service-wrapper').on(...);
```

Comment: _doesn't work_ .... is not explaining the issue can you elaborate more. what is the current issue? Do you see any error in console?

Comment: Just nothing. No error, no any action when I click on dynamically added button. But button, what rendered in server(not dynamically) action (alert) work fine.

Answer (score 1):

You try to attach the event handler to an element which doesn't exists in your DOM structure. Before adding `on('click')` try to console log `$('.service')`. You need to use event delegation: https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/
So in your case:

```
$( ".service-wrapper" ).on( "click", ".delete-service", function( event ) {
  event.preventDefault();
  alert('Clicked');
});
```

Comment: I tryed on $(document) - doesn't work. And element is exists in DOM.

Comment: Try to use different HTML events like 'mousedown' or 'mouseover', maybe something is stopping event bubbling

Comment: Nope, 'mouseover' doesn't work too :( I don't know, why this delegate event doesn't work..

Comment: You need to help us to help you, create some jsFiddle and paste the URL to your question

Answer (score 0):

```
$("body").on('click','.delete-service',function(){
     alert('Clicked');
});
```

Try this

Comment: Tryed(and document, other parent elements), nope(